# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 on NSCFString

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, native, codenameone

I have a class in Objective C that discovers Network printers. I do find my printer, but when my code later [after exiting DiscoverDevices] checks for null/trims the device list, it throws a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2`. I am new to Objective C and really need your help here. Feel free to code review as well.

I suspect `PrinterCallBack_PUT_bluetoothDevices([jsonString description]);`
some issues with the String format/address but not sure

Code as follows:

```
#import "DiscoverDevices.h"    
#import "ePOS-Print.h"    
#import "java_lang_String.h";
#import "org_json_me_JSONObject.h";

#define DISCOVERY_INTERVAL  0.5

@interface DiscoverDevices()
- (void)timerFindPrinter:(NSTimer*)timer;
- (void)findStart;    
- (void) doNothing;    
@end    

@implementation DiscoverDevices    
@synthesize delegate = delegate_;   


- (id)init {    
    self = [super init];    
    if (self) {    
        printerList_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
    }    
    [self findStart];    
    [self timerFindPrinter:timer_];    
    //TODO:find a better way to wait till printer is discovered here    
    // for now works    
     for (int i=0; i<500; i++) {
        if (printerList_.count>0) {
            break;    
        }    
        [self timerFindPrinter:timer_];    
    }
    NSLog(@"-----printerList = %@",printerList_);
    NSError * error;    
    NSMutableDictionary *dictObj = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<printerList_.count; i++) {    
        NSLog(@"printerList[%d] = %@",i,printerList_[i]);    
        [dictObj setObject:printerList_[i] forKey:printerList_[i]];    
        NSLog(@"jsonobject put [%d]",i);    
    }    
    NSLog(@"Dict : %@",dictObj);    
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictObj options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    if (!jsonData) {    
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@",error);    
    } else {    
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
        jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];    
        jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        NSLog(@"In native discoverDevices devices found jsonstring = %@, %s", jsonString, object_getClassName([jsonString class]));

        if ([jsonString length]>2) {                
                    // This is where we set the list of printers found.
                    com_nvsoft_s2pay_print_PrinterCallBack_PUT_bluetoothDevices([jsonString description]);
                    NSLog(@"In native discoverDevices written json to callback now reading....");
                    NSLog(@"In native discoverDevices from cback json = %@, %s", com_nvsoft_s2pay_print_PrinterCallBack_GET_bluetoothDevices(),object_getClassName([com_nvsoft_s2pay_print_PrinterCallBack_GET_bluetoothDevices() class]));
            }else{


            com_nvsoft_s2pay_print_PrinterCallBack_PUT_bluetoothDevices(nil);    
        }

            com_nvsoft_s2pay_print_PrinterCallBack_PUT_result(1);    
            NSLog(@"In native discoverDevices completed jsondaata");    
        }    
        NSLog(@"In native discoverDevices exiting after jsondaata");    
        NSLog(@"In native discoverDevices from cback json = %@", com_nvsoft_s2pay_print_PrinterCallBack_GET_bluetoothDevices());    
        return self;    
    }    


- (void)dealloc    
{    
    [printerList_ release];    
    [super dealloc];    
}
//find printer timer    
- (void)timerFindPrinter:(NSTimer*)timer    
{    
    NSLog(@"In timerFindPrinter");    
    int result = 0;    
    NSArray *items = [EpsonIoFinder getResult:&result];
    if(items != nil && result ==EPSONIO_OC_SUCCESS){    
        bool change = NO;    
        if([printerList_ count] != [items count]){    
            [printerList_ release];    
            printerList_ = [items retain];    
            change = YES;    
        }    
        /*if(change){    
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doNothing) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];    
         }*/    
    }    
}
  //find start/restart    
- (void)findStart    
{    
    NSLog(@"In findStart");    
    //stop old finder    
    [EpsonIoFinder stop];    
    //stop find timer    
    if(timer_ != nil){    
        [timer_ invalidate];    
        [timer_ release];    
        timer_ = nil;   
    }
    //clear list
    [printerList_ release];    
    printerList_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
    //if(printerView_ != nil){    
    //    [printerView_ reloadData];    
    //}   

    //find start
        int result = [EpsonIoFinder start:EPSONIO_OC_DEVTYPE_TCP FindOption:@"255.255.255.255"];    
    if(result != EPSONIO_OC_SUCCESS){
            return ;
        }
    //start timer    
    timer_ = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:DISCOVERY_INTERVAL   
                                              target:self  
                                            selector:@selector(timerFindPrinter:)   
                                            userInfo:nil    
                                             repeats:YES];    
}
@end
```

My console output was:

```
2014-02-26 11:50:24.661 S2PayApp[10749:1807] -----printerList = (

   "192.168.0.13"

)

2014-02-26 11:50:24.662 S2PayApp[10749:1807] printerList[0] = 192.168.0.13

2014-02-26 11:50:24.662 S2PayApp[10749:1807] jsonobject put [0]

2014-02-26 11:50:24.663 S2PayApp[10749:1807] Dict : {

   "192.168.0.13" = "192.168.0.13";

}

2014-02-26 11:50:24.664 S2PayApp[10749:1807] In native discoverDevices devices found jsonstring = {"192.168.0.13":"192.168.0.13"}, __NSCFString

2014-02-26 11:50:24.664 S2PayApp[10749:1807] In native discoverDevices written json to callback now reading....

2014-02-26 11:50:24.665 S2PayApp[10749:1807] In native discoverDevices from cback json = {"192.168.0.13":"192.168.0.13"}, __NSCFString

2014-02-26 11:50:24.665 S2PayApp[10749:1807] In native discoverDevices completed 
jsondaata

2014-02-26 11:50:24.666 S2PayApp[10749:1807] In native discoverDevices exiting after jsondaata

2014-02-26 11:50:24.667 S2PayApp[10749:1807] In native discoverDevices from cback json = {"192.168.0.13":"192.168.0.13"}

2014-02-26 11:50:24.667 S2PayApp[10749:1807] --3-- In native discoverDevices from cback json = {"192.168.0.13":"192.168.0.13"}

2014-02-26 11:50:24.668 S2PayApp[10749:1807] completed discoveing ntwk printers

2014-02-26 11:50:24.669 S2PayApp[10749:1807] devices r9= {"192.168.0.13":"192.168.0.13"},__NSCFString

2014-02-26 11:50:24.669 S2PayApp[10749:1807] devices r4= {"192.168.0.13":"192.168.0.13"},__NSCFString
(lldb)
```

Here's the exact class where his code breaks:

```
JAVA_BOOLEAN com_nvsoft_s2pay_util_StringUtil_isEmpty___java_lang_String(JAVA_OBJECT n1)
{
    if (!__TIB_com_nvsoft_s2pay_util_StringUtil.classInitialized) __INIT_com_nvsoft_s2pay_util_StringUtil();
    //XMLVM_BEGIN_WRAPPER[com_nvsoft_s2pay_util_StringUtil_isEmpty___java_lang_String]
    XMLVM_ENTER_METHOD("com.nvsoft.s2pay.util.StringUtil", "isEmpty", "?")
    XMLVMElem _r0;
    XMLVMElem _r1;
    XMLVMElem _r2;
    _r2.o = n1;
    XMLVM_SOURCE_POSITION("StringUtil.java", 152)
    //NSLog(@"In StringUtil devices r2= %@", _r2.o);
    if (_r2.o == JAVA_NULL) goto label22;
    XMLVM_CHECK_NPE(2)
    _r0.o = java_lang_String_trim__(_r2.o);
    // ""
    _r1.o = xmlvm_create_java_string_from_pool(13);
    //NSLog(@"In StringUtil devices r0= %@,%s", _r0.o);
    //NSLog(@"In StringUtil devices r1= %@,%s", _r1.o);

    //java_lang_String_equals___java_lang_Object[1]
    XMLVM_CHECK_NPE(0)
//************ Code breaks here
    _r0.i = (*(JAVA_BOOLEAN (*)(JAVA_OBJECT, JAVA_OBJECT)) ((java_lang_String*) _r0.o)->tib->vtable[1])(_r0.o, _r1.o);
    if (_r0.i != 0) goto label22;
    // "null"
    _r0.o = xmlvm_create_java_string_from_pool(9);
    //java_lang_String_equals___java_lang_Object[1]
    XMLVM_CHECK_NPE(2)
    _r0.i = (*(JAVA_BOOLEAN (*)(JAVA_OBJECT, JAVA_OBJECT)) ((java_lang_String*) _r2.o)->tib->vtable[1])(_r2.o, _r0.o);
    if (_r0.i == 0) goto label24;
    label22:;
    _r0.i = 1;
    label23:;
    XMLVM_EXIT_METHOD()
    return _r0.i;
    label24:;
    _r0.i = 0;
    goto label23;
    //XMLVM_END_WRAPPER
}
```

Comment: on which line do you get exc_bad_access? I cannot see any trace of it in your log output...

Comment: Goto Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Diagnostic, Check mark `Enable Zombie Objects` and then put the trace here.

Comment: Enabling the Zombies didnt change anything. Same Console output & error message. I am using Codenameone generated source and iOS native code. The code here works but later after exiting this class, it fails. Attaching the code in following comment.

Comment: XMLVM_SOURCE_POSITION("StateMachine.java", 12444)  _r4.o = com_nvsoft_s2pay_print_PrinterCallBack_getBluetoothDevices__();    
    NSLog(@"devices r4= %@,%s", _r4.o, object_getClassName([_r4.o class]));    
    XMLVM_SOURCE_POSITION("StateMachine.java", 12445)  
    _r9.i = com_nvsoft_s2pay_util_StringUtil_isEmpty___java_lang_String(_r4.o);   
//The last line is what gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

When you see that sort of crash the failure is elsewhere. I'm guessing you have a memory corruption somewhere which resulted in this. Often this is caused by invoking a c function with the wrong argument types or accessing invalid memory by keeping a reference to a GC'd object or keeping a reference to a released Objective-C object.

You can see the call stack in a crash in the left hand side in xcode just toggle between the modes there and you should see all your threads with a nice stack that should give you an indication of what is going on. Its a bit confusing though since the main iOS thread is a bit obtuse.